# Docker: Cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I can't run any binary in my docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:eoan AS compiler-build

RUN apt-get update && \
    dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get install -y gcc \
                       gcc-multilib \
                       make \
                       cmake \
                       git \
                       python3.8 \
                       bash

WORKDIR /home
ADD . /home/pawn
RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /home/build
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I can't even use `file` builtin:

```
[root@LAPTOP-EJ5BH6DJ compiler]:~/dev/private/SAMP/compiler (v13.11.0) (master) dc run compiler file bash
/usr/bin/file: /usr/bin/file: cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From [this forum thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2109):

> This error occurs when you use a shell in your entrypoint without the "-c" argument

So, if you change your `Dockerfile` to end with

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]
```

then you can run binary files.

Note the purpose of the options for `/bin/bash`, from the manpage:

- `-l`: Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
- `-c`: If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument `command_string`. If there are arguments after the `command_string`, the first argument is assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to `$0` sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Additionally, [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170714072459/https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/) is a worthwhile read on how to use both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together, and what their differences are.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint)'s another article that goes into a trivial (but clearer than the first article) example using the `echo` shell builtin.

**EDIT:** Here's an adaptation of the trivial example from the second article I linked:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]
CMD [ "ls" ]
```

```
$ docker build -t test .

$ docker run --rm test
bin
boot
...
var

$ docker run --rm test "ls etc"
adduser.conf
alternatives
apt
...
update-motd.d
xattr.conf
```

Note the `"` around `ls /etc`. Without the quotes, the argument `/etc` doesn't seem to be passed to the `ls` command as I might expect.

Comment: Could you give me a pointer how this is done in practice?

Comment: @altabq Sorry for taking a while to get back to you. [Here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint)'s another article that goes over a trivial example using the `echo` shell builtin that I think is a bit clearer than the original article I linked.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170714072459/https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/ wayback machine for the dead link

Comment: @scaryman Thanks for pointing that out; just updated the answer with your link

Answer (score 7):

Entrypoint can't point to `/bin/bash` it seems. Removing
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]` is enough to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same error. Unlike the other answers, my error was related to my `docker run` parameters:

```
# failed
docker run -it $(pwd | xargs basename):latest bash

# worked
docker run -it $(pwd | xargs basename):latest
```

I didn't need to add `bash` as I already had this in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are times when we don't have control over the image's Dockerfile but it's original entrypoint has an issue.

We could overwrite it's entrypoint to debug issues:

```
# example
docker run --rm \
    --entrypoint /bin/bash \
    -it apache/spark-py:v3.3.0
```