# Ubuntu 18.04.6 "dockerd: dockerd: cannot execute binary file" Using "su root dockerd""

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, docker-daemon

When i use this in Ubuntu 18.04.6

> su root dockerd

It returns

> dockerd: dockerd: cannot execute binary file
> Please help me.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to this works without this error

Comment: please describe whole problem you have. what program you want to run. when you say "this" it's not understandable what exactly you would like to run.

Comment: I suppose that you're trying to launch something with docker, but you ahve to provide with additional info. try to look already existing questions like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055324/docker-cannot-execute-binary-file

Comment: I want to use Docker's daemon command. It is dockerd. My docker command dont works someone says to use dockerd first with sudo but my sudo dont works. Then i used su root dockerd. But that gives this error.

Comment: "> I want to use Docker's daemon command." To do what? try `sudo docker <here comes your command> `, and read https://xyproblem.info/ for asking good questions